# What are the advantages for certain types of transformers?

Tags: motor, transformer

I work designing medium voltage motor starters. Being an mechanical engineer, I still don't understand the advantages, disadvantages, and when to use certain types of transformers.
When is wye-wye best?
When is delta-delta best?
When is delta-wye best?
When is wye-delta best?

Comment: VTC as a duplicate of an existing post.